# "I want [to make] IT" but "The fan asked HER [to leave]" - why objects have different positions relative to infinitive verbs?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, infinitive-clauses

Could anyone please tell me the sequence of **object and infinitive verb** in sentence as some time infinitive verb comes before object, whereas some time it comes later?

So is there any rule? Or how to decide orders of them?

> 1. I want **to make it** (Infinitive verb comes before object)
> 2. The crazed fan even threatened to blow up his house when he asked her **to leave**. (object comes before Infinitive verb)

Please help me understand the above one.

Thanks,
Charmi

Comment: Could you please tell me what is incorrect in second one, so alteast i come to know. Regarding order, is there any rule? then please share it.

Comment: Sorry CopperKettle, there is a correction in second setence. The crazed fan even threatened to blow up his house when he asked her to leave. (object comes before Infinitive verb)

Comment: Dear CopperKettle, could you please suggest any rule regarding sequence of object and infinitive verb?

Comment: @CopperKettle, I suggest we clean up all extraneous comments at this point.

Answer (score 1):

> “I want [to make] IT”

*IT* is an object of *to make*.

> “The fan asked HER [to leave]”

*HER* is an object of *asked*, not *to leave*, so it's in the right spot.

If *to leave* had an object, it'd be like this:

> "The fan asked HER to leave the stadium"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, and as I know "to leave" is an infinitive verb. Right.  So is there any possibility in sentence where infinitive verb may work as an object of sentence then I request you to provide an example.
If you have any prototype/rules/Structure to frame a sentence then I request you to provide me the one you have as sometime I used to be confused by myself in term of order of infinitive verb and object